# Не считываются данные из таблицы БД

Tags: php, база-данных

Помогите найти ошибку. не считываются данные из таблицы БД. В ячейка таблицы пустота. Даже не знаю как отладить. Значение `mysql_query($query): Resource id #5`

часть кода:

```
<?php

// соединение
$connection = mysql_connect ("localhost", "root") or die ("Ошибка соединения с сервером");

// создание базы данных
$query = "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS yogaclass";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die ("Ошибка при создании базы данных: ".mysql_error());

// создание таблицы
$db = mysql_select_db ("yogaclass", $connection) or die ("Ошибка при выборе базы данных");

$query = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS monday (time varchar(20), class varchar(20), instructor varchar(20) )";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die ("Ошибка при создании таблицы: ".mysql_error());

$query = "INSERT INTO monday (time, class, instructor) values ('16:45-16:50','Hatha','Ann Tagiltseva')";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die ("Ошибка при добавлении данных: ".mysql_error());

$query = "INSERT INTO monday (time, class, instructor) values ('16:45-16:50','Hatha','Ann Tagiltseva')";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die ("Ошибка при добавлении данных: ".mysql_error());

$query = "SELECT * FROM monday";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die ("Ошибка при выполнении запроса: ".mysql_error());

echo 'Отладочная информация: ', mysql_query($query);                            
// значение (ошибка) mysql_query($query): Resource id #5

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array ($result)){?>
<td><?php $row['time']?></td> // в ячейках ничего нет
<td><?php $row['class']?></td>
<td><?php $row['instructor']?></td>
<?php
}

mysql_close($connection);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

эммм... а резве не так надо писать? через echo

```
<td><?php echo $row['time']; ?></td> // в ячейках ничего нет
<td><?php echo $row['class']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['instructor']; ?></td>
```

Comment: Вроде если включены php short tags то можно и так.

Comment: @Олег Б, если включены php short tags то нужно так <?= $row['class']; ?>

Answer (score 1):

Я бы даже сказал, так лучше.

```
<td><?php echo !empty($row['time']) ? $row['time'] : 'empty';?></td> // в ячейках ничего нет 
<td><?php echo !empty($row['class']) ? $row['class'] : 'empty';?></td> 
<td><?php echo !empty($row['instructor']) ? $row['instructor'] : 'empty';?></td>
```